# Nginx, run script from separate directory

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

File structure:

- /var/www/example.com - the directory with the Laravel site
- /var/www/cms - the directory with the WordPress blog

I want to open my blog by address http://example.com/blogs (http://example.com/blogs/article/)

My nginx config file

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    charset UTF-8;
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/example.com/public;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;

    location ^~ /blogs/ {
        alias /var/www/cms;
                index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
                     try_files /does_not_exists @php;
                }
    }

    location / {
        if ($http_host !~ "^example.com") {
            return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;

        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
    }

    location @php {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location @fallback {
    }
    ssi on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
}
```

drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct  7 12:36 /var/www/cms

-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 28 Oct  7 12:36 /var/www/cms/index.php

But I get error:

[error] 1193696#1193696: *69 directory index of "/var/www/cms" is forbidden, client: 89.69.169.171, server: example.com, request: "GET /blogs/ HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com"

I tried to add `autoindex on;`

```
    location ^~ /blogs/ {
        alias /var/www/cms;
                index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        autoindex on;

        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
                    try_files /does_not_exists @php;
                }
    }
```

But got next error
[warn] 1192265#1192265: *92 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/1/00/0000000001 while reading upstream, client: 89.69.169.171, server: example.com, request: "GET /_debugbar/assets/javascript/?v=1695127990 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/blogs/"

How too fix such error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    location /blogs {
        alias "/var/www/cms";
        try_files $uri $uri/ @blogs;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/blogs/index.php;
        }
    }
    location @blogs {
        rewrite /blogs/(.*)$ /blogs/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
```